# Unexpected end of file syntax error in .bash_profile file

Tags: bash

I am getting `.bash_profile: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file`. The content of my .bash_profile file is shown below. I can't figure out where the issue is

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

alias bash_profile="source ~/.bash_profile";

if [-f "$HOME/.config/bash/config.bash"]; then source $HOME/.config/bash/config.bash fi
```

Comment: your last `if` condition should have spaces between `[` and `]`, like this: `if [ -f "$HOME/.config/bash/config.bash" ]`

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will automatically detect common syntax issues including these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the 'if [ ... ]' line. Correct version is:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.config/bash/config.bash" ]; then source $HOME/.config/bash/config.bash ; fi
```

1. Missing space between '[' and '-f'
2. Missing space between 'config.bash"' and ']'
3. Missing semicolon before the 'fi' to terminate 'source' command

In general, you always want conditions like [ expr ] to be separated with spaces from the '[' and ']'.